# Понятие "ингредиент" и понятия "добавка", "приправа"

Tags: семантика

Всякий ли ингредиент, входящий в состав блюда, можно назвать добавкой и приправой? Например, горох в гороховом супе, или томаты в салате.

Answer (score 1):

Приправы обычно являются обязательным ингредиентом на одном уровне со всеми остальными.

СПЕЦИИ — добавляют в кушанье в процессе готовки для того, чтобы усилить вкус, сделать его сладким, соленым или острым. Соль, сахар, сода, уксус, лимонная кислота, дрожжи и алкоголь — вот настоящие специи!
Специи – это особый регулятор интенсивности вкуса и консистенции блюда. Они не создают многогранных вкусовых оттенков, никак не влияют на запах, при этом могут быть абсолютно любого происхождения. Наиболее известными являются картофельный крахмал, пищевая сода, уксус, соль.
ПРИПРАВА — более широкое понятие. В ее составе могут быть и специи, и пряности, и ароматизаторы, а могут и не быть. Например, когда мы заливаем грибы сметаной — сметана будет считаться приправой. К обширному семейству приправ относятся все соусы, кетчупы, сухие смеси пряностей и специй.
http://www.priprava.by/prjanosti-pripravy-specii-v-chem-raznica/

Добавка — само слово означает факультативность (дополнительные добавки к шаурме за деньги). Но и приправа может быть необязательной (добавкой).

Comment: То есть говорить "Приправить салат томатами" (если, к примеру, изначально томаты не предполагались в качестве ингредиента) неправильно?

Comment: Ну томаты же не приправа. А вот кетчуп из томатов - другое дело.

Answer (score 0):

Нет, не всякий ингредиент можно назвать добавкой или приправой.

Добавка - это то, что *добавляется к чему-то*. Т.е. должны быть некие ингредиенты, являющиеся **основой**, к которым добавляется добавка.
Ну а [приправы](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F:%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%8B) - это еще более узкая категория ингредиентов.

Таким образом, далеко не всякий ингредиент является добавкой или приправой.

Исключением являются смеси, целиком состоящие из добавок и приправ, например смеси специй. В них все ингредиенты могут быть пищевыми добавками/приправами.